# Wordpress a:2:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;} vs a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;} causing "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page"

Tags: wordpress, permissions, administrator

I have "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page." issue when trying to access Wordpress wp-admin login as an administrator. The login page appears, but when the user details are entered the "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page." appears.

The strange part is that I have another administrator account that accesses with no error.

I tried to create a new administrator account, but that also cannot access giving the above error message.

I have looked into the database and the users that don't work have `wp_capabilities` of `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}`

The user that does work has: `a:2:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;s:13:"bbp_keymaster";b:1;}`

I am also running S2 Member plugin.

The only difference I can see between the account is this beginning section of `a:1` and `a:2`. All of the sites I see say the account should be a:1

I don't think it is a plugin issue, as I assume then I would not be able to access either. I think perhaps something to do with s" Member plugin, but I'm now at a bi of a loss.

All plugins are updated and running Wordpress 4.0 (however this was an issue even before upgrade to 4.0)

All help gratefully received!

Answer (score 1):

> The only difference I can see between the account is this beginning section of a:1 and a:2.

Look more carefully. The working example has a whole extra section: `s:13:"bbp_keymaster";b:1;`

To understand why that matters, it helps to know that that is the format produced by by PHP's [`serialize()` function](http://php.net/serialize).

If you unserialize each of those strings, you will find that the first is an array with 1 entry (hence `a:1`), with the key 'administrator' and a value of `true`. The longer string is an array with that entry plus another one, with the key 'bbp_keymaster', also set to `true`.

From this, it's easy to surmise that 'administrator' and 'bbp_keymaster' are the internal names for permissions which can be granted to a user, and the page in question is only available to users with the 'bbp_keymaster' permission.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I should have clarified that I meant the only difference between the a:1 and a:2 section, I realised there was extra information on the a:1 user. I still don't understand why the user with the bbp_keymaster section would be able to log in. I don't know why this has changed, but my other Administrator user still shows as a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;} and has not had the bbp_keymaster? Should all my administrators have bbp_keymaster assigned to them to?

Comment: @Amanda It's an extra permission, presumably required for certain pages. You need to grant it to whatever users you want to be able to access those pages.